# Product price turns zero($0) when I add product to cart

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-theming

Product price turns zero($0) when I add the product to cart
I have products in my woocomerce shop page. I don't have any problem with my product page. But when I add the product to cart, Product price turns zero($0) 
I couldn't find any solution to this problem until now
[Product Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fQaS.jpg)

[After adding the product to cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqfl7.jpg)

Comment: killer deal? I don't get it

Comment: nevermind, it was just a joke. btw, since figuring this out most likely requires inspection of your woocommerce settings, i don't think anyone here is able to help you unless you post configuration files and stuff like that. i'm no expert on woocommerce though

Comment: The problem is that the product-price class in woocommerce doesn't pull product price from the product page. This should be my problem. But I can't figure out. I hope there is some master can handle my problem

Comment: As mentioned in a previous comment, without additional information the community will not be able to help much. At the very lest, we would need to know how the software is configured? if you found anything interesting while debugging the issue? Is there an error in the log file or the console?etc